# How can I achive this in react redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

So, I have the posts array that is mapping in a page. when I clicked on each post it will open in modal.

Posts have a like button so, I want when user Like the post while it's open in modal it will automatically update that post liked status in that feed where all posts are mapped over.

[image: Scenario]

Now, when I like the post I receive the following response in the payload:

```
{
   id: "620ca78f3b36d45714ca4c1e"
   postId: "6dks2b92bjd99sndkd9j3",
   liked: true
   msg: "You liked the post."
   success: true
}
```

Now the question is how do I update the likes array from the post array.

**Single Post Structure**

```
{
   _id,
   ...other,
   likes: [],
}
```

```
const updatedPost = (find that specific post from the array using the postId I recieved and update its likes array)
return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        post: [...state.posts, updatedPost],
        data: payload,
      };
```

Comment: You can set a function that dispatches after liking any image in the modal. 
And in that function you can map over the posts array and can find the current post using its ID and can change its status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to find index of the specific post by id or whatever unique entity you are using. And then change posts array at that index by assigning new post details to it.

```
const postIndex = state.posts.findIndex((p)=>p.id===payload.id);
let posts=[...state.posts];
if(postIndex!=-1){
    posts[postIndex]=updatedPost; // updatedPost Object whatever you want to change
    // for appending likes i.e.,
    // posts[postIndex].likes.push('id') // sample
  
}
state.loading=false; // use this scheme for updating state
state.error=null;
state.posts=posts;
state.data=payload;
```

Comment: how do I update the likes array  of that post. I wanna push that like id in the likes array.

Comment: updated answer in comments I have write logic of it too

Comment: I am getting this error:     errors.ts:49 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.

Comment: Kindly update your code in question so that we can figure out the error

Comment: Are you using redux toolkit or simple react-redux?

Comment: I'm using redux toolkit

Comment: Then in redux tookit we dont have to return the new object of state as it manages automatically. So I am updating the code for redux toolkit please change it

Comment: Updated code. Please provide feedback

Comment: In redux toolkit, if you want to update the particular state entity then, we simply use state.entity=newEntity. e.g., in your case if you only want to update posts then use state.posts=updatedPosts.

Comment: ok the errors gone but didn't update the post. :((

Comment: Are you checking the state in dev tools or component?

Comment: In your component, use useSelector hook for accessing state. And add reducername which you are using if you have multiple reducers and used combineReducer too.
Like: const posts=useSelector((state)=>state.reducerName.posts);

Comment: getting null in the likes array.

Comment: Make sure you have initially set likes to empty array or initially typeof likes should be array. and your payload._id should not be null

Comment: Check the update v2.

Comment: It might be possible that your posts object which you have saved earlier or fetched from some API have some error or you have some logical errors in it. Because the syntax is fine.

Comment: the data is fetched perfectly, well let me figure out I will update the answer.

Comment: Done, I was pushing the wrong Id in the array. Thanks